# Moving Pivot Table template from csv(Excel) to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I usually prepare reports and charts from excel manually using pivot table adding several columns manually from the raw data and then using pivot table on the fields and populating it.

And I would like to see if this can be automated by:

> a) Loading the data into a mysql database 
>   b) Using several queries to add additional columns and then prepare the data ready to be used by 
>   c) Chart APIs/JQuery.

Since I know csv to mysql is easier, I now have the raw data file in CSV format.

The raw data basically contains different fields mainly time, date time and strings.

Using a PHP script, I was able to load these data using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command.

Based on dates, I need to prepare a column y which says months and this month column has to be updated with the month name('jan', etc.) depending on the date field`(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) on certain x column in the same table.

or maybe just use this and reference in the graphs(Not sure how complex that would be):-

```
mysql> select count(*) as Count,  monthname(date) from alerts;
+-------+---------------------------------+
| Count | monthname(date) |
+-------+---------------------------------+
| 24124 | March                           |
+-------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.19 sec)
```

Similarly, I need a column a that says "Duration < 5 minutes" and a column b that says "Duration > 5 min < 10 min" , where I would put a numeric value '1', if it falls within the range.

I looked into the self-join examples but I could not make it work in my case inspite of several efforts.

I need some help to get me going because my belief is that a table with all relevant columns is better off than using queries at runtime.
Also, is it better to format the data first and load it to mysql OR load the data and format it?
Please let me know.

Thanks

**Update1**

Okay, I got this working with a self join as below

```
UPDATE t1 p1 INNER JOIN ( select monthname(dt_received) AS EXTMONTHNAME from t1)p2 SET     p1.MONTH=p2.EXTMONTHNAME;
```

but why does it update all the month with the same month name even though dt_received has other months ?
Can someone help?

**Update2**
Again, still struggling, I was made aware of the 1093 error/constraint. The workarounds are simply not helping

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Excel where manual formatting was required, I found querying the database much easier using queryies

This resolved the issue

```
UPDATE tablename p1 INNER JOIN ( select monthname(dt_received) AS EXTMONTHNAME from tablename )p2 SET p1.MONTH=p2.EXTMONTHNAME where monthname(p1.dt_received)=p2.EXTMONTHNAME;
```

But would someone know, why it takes close to 14 minutes to change 36879 rows?
How do I optimize it.